# Problems with HID Host and STM32F4

Tags: c, host, hid, stm32f4, usb-hostcontroller

I'm developing an HID Host application to comunicate with a own device and I'm using the NUCLEO-F446ZE board.
At the start I tried to use the HID_Standalone application in the STM32CubeF4 firmware package and then, I tried to develop a new application with STMCube configurator.

In both case I tried to connect (with OTG connector) 3 different type of mouse and 1 keyboard and no all device are able to comunicate with microcontroller:

- with Typhoon mouse 40260 the USBH_Process state machine in the usbh_core.c file of the Middlewares, blocks in the HOST_ENUMERATION state (line 462) because the USBH_HandleEnum(phost) function try to get device descriptior (line 646 same file) but the USBH_HandleControl() function read all times USBH_URB_NOTREADY state (line 600 of usbh_ctlreq.c) until HAL_HCD_Disconnect_Callback() called by interrupt.
- with Trust mouse 16144 is the same with Typhoon mouse with difference that the HAL_HCD_Disconnect_Callback() isn't called by interrupt.
- with Dell Mouse XN966 all work fine and I can see the data.
- with asus keyboard G01 KB the USBH_Process state machine in the usbh_core.c come up to HOST_DEV_DISCONNECTED where there is the BgndProcess but I can't receive data because in the HID_Handle the fifo has the tail and head at the same value.

All the previous devices are tested with PC and work fine and the board are powerd with external source.

What can be the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you can post simplify your question and put some code here .

Comment: Sorry, I edited question because wasn't formatted correctly.

It's a little bit difficult to put code because I have to write a lot of ST library code. It's possible to consult it by downloading the libraries: https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-mcu-packages/stm32cubef4.html

Comment: I continued debugging code and I saw the problem is the device send to the host STALL handshake when the host try to enumerate or, with a custom device different from previosus devices, when it call SetReport or GetReport.

I read on-line that the device return STALL handshake when endpoint is in HALT state.

What could be the problem?